# How to create and initialize a static readonly array of struct, inside a class?

Tags: c#, arrays, static, constants

Say I have a struct like

```
public struct pair{ float x,y;}
```

I want to create a constant lookup array of pairs inside a class, its also fixed number.
Something like

```
public class MyClass{
    static readonly fixed pair[7] _lookup;
}
```

I dont know how to declare nor initialize it(where do I set the values for each one?).

Comment: can you explain what you mean: _how to declare nor initialize it_?

Comment: I dont know the correct syntax, and I dont know how to initialize it with the values I want.

Comment: you can start from [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a static constructor

```
public struct pair
{
    float x, y;

    public pair(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static readonly pair[] lookup;

    static MyClass()
    {
        lookup = new pair[7] { new pair(1, 2), new pair(2, 3), new pair(3, 4), new pair(4, 5), new pair(5, 6), new pair(6, 7), new pair(7, 8) };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using structures similar using classes, so you can assign value on definition

```
public struct Pair {public float x, y;}

public class MyClass
{
    public static readonly Pair[] _lookup = new Pair[]{ 
        new Pair(){x=1, y=2}, 
        new Pair(){x=1, y=2},
        new Pair(){x=1, y=2},
        new Pair(){x=1, y=2},
        new Pair(){x=1, y=2},
        new Pair(){x=1, y=2},
        new Pair(){x=1, y=2}
    };
}
```